# Careers sidebar has an incorrect location

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

On my box, in the careers sidebar, it displays jobs from the Chicago area
[image]

My ISP reports my IP address as being in that area.

However, I am REALLY in Minnesota.

I have entered my geographical data in my profile but Careers seems to be using the IP information instead.

Comment: I think that's come up before and is considered by design... that said, it would be really cool to be able to define which area the banner should target.

Comment: If it is by design, then the design is wrong because it is giving me useless information.

Comment: Your ISP is providing useless information

Comment: I think it would be nice to have an override for it. ISP's are garbage for the most part in America, and a lot of people use VPN's which may have different information as well.

Comment: My ISP reports correctly, but most of the jobs in the sidebar are irrelevant anyway. If I want to look at Careers, I click through. **2¢**

Comment: @SysDragon My ISP is providing incorrect information.  But that is reality and we should deal with it.  I have provided the correct information in my profile.

Comment: There is always the flip side of course that people don't update their profile when they relocate, or might be at a conference in a remote location and decide they like the area, which would make sidebar ads relevant again.  Perhaps a weighted mix might be better when we can identify the user on Careers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, currently this is by design, since by design we only look to IP for geo data.  It doesn't mean this is how it will always be.  We want to be smarter about how we deliver you jobs, and this isn't good enough.

Your self identification of where you are should trump the crummy data we do have, and we want to make it work.

The good news is, we're working on making our ads better!  This is part of a large project to make ads more relevant and bringing the right candidate and the right employer together.

Comment: Hey....I think it's working now and takes the address I enter rather than the IP.   Thank God I don't have to move to Chicago now!